# Making short lists from LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an array of objects with multiple fields - id, name, age, weight, owner - how do I use LINQ to make shorter lists containing only name and owner?

I can write the LINQ query, but how do I put that into a list / array / dictionary that I can then access the name and owner individually?

```
Animal[] pets = {
            new Animal() { id=1, name="Rover", age=3, weight=40, owner="Dave"},
            new Animal() { id=2, name="Benji", age=4, weight=50, owner="Sue"},
            new Animal() { id=3, name="Spot", age=2, weight=20, owner="Cheryl"},
            new Animal() { id=4, name="Kitty", age=3, weight=15, owner="Joyce"},
            new Animal() { id=5, name="Oscar", age=1, weight=15, owner="Mike"}
        };

        // Make an array containing only NAME and OWNER

        var linqPetOwner = from p in pets
                          select new
                          {
                              p.name,
                              p.owner
                          };
        
        // Create what? A dictionary? A list ? An Array?
        Dictionary<string, string> petOwnerDict =  linqPetOwner.ToDict()????
        
        // No idea how to access the name and owner individually ????
        foreach ( i in petOwnerDict){
            Console(WriteLine( i.name + " is owned by " + i.owner);
        }
```

Thanks for reading. All the tutorials I have seen just output it to an array with myArray = linqPetOwner.ToArray() but then don't show you how to access the name or owner individually.

Comment: What data type do you want to store those values in? A dictionary would work fine until one of the keys is duplicated (both owner names and pet names are not guaranteed to be unique, i assume). What's wrong with `linqPetOwner`? Just add a `.ToList()` after it and you should be fine.

Comment: Why not do `foreach (var i in linqPetOwner){` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a list containing only the properties you want. You can iterate on it like this:

```
foreach (var i in linqPetOwner){
   Console.WriteLine( i.name + " is owned by " + i.owner);
}
```

That being said, your method can't return this list as it uses an anonymous type. To be able to return this list, you'll have to create a type, 1or return a list of Tuples, or return a dynamic IEnumerable:

Using a type:

```
public class AnimalShort
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public AnimalShort(string name, string owner) { Name = name; Owner = owner }
}

public static List<AnimalShort> GetList()
{
    Animal[] pets = {
        new Animal() { id=1, name="Rover", age=3, weight=40, owner="Dave"},
        new Animal() { id=2, name="Benji", age=4, weight=50, owner="Sue"},
    };

    return pets.Select(p => new AnimalShort(p.name, p.owner)).ToList();
}
```

Using a list of tuples:

```
public static List<(string name, string owner)> GetList()
{
    Animal[] pets = {
        new Animal() { id=1, name="Rover", age=3, weight=40, owner="Dave"},
        new Animal() { id=2, name="Benji", age=4, weight=50, owner="Sue"},
    };

    return pets.Select(p => CreateNameOwnerTuple(p.name, p.owner)).ToList();

    (string name, string owner) CreateNameOwnerTuple(string name, string owner) => (name, owner);
}
```

Using a dynamic IEnumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetList()
{
    Animal[] pets = {
        new Animal() { id=1, name="Rover", age=3, weight=40, owner="Dave"},
        new Animal() { id=2, name="Benji", age=4, weight=50, owner="Sue"},
    };

    return pets.Select(p => new {p.name, p.owner}).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, silly of me to not know linq returned a list. I'm just learning it. Thanks very much for the pointer about this being an anonymous type as well!

Comment: I've been there :)

Answer (score 1):

You had to declare I, and you can use the same for each to populate the dictionary.

```
foreach (var i in linqPetOwner)
petOwnerDict.add(i.name,i.owner);
```

Comment: this doesn't solve how to populate the `petOwnerDict`, which is the main question I think...

Comment: I updated my answer to use dictionary.add

Comment: The dictionary is not created, though...`linqPetOwner.ToDict()????`

Comment: Changed to use the right variable.  The other way to do it is var res = linqPetOwner.ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.owner)

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanation on how to use .ToDictionary()

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you can use the `ToDictionary` linq extension method to create a dictionary of name/owner pairs, but you must recognize that all the keys must be unique or you'll get an exception:

```
// All pet names must be unique or this will fail
Dictionary<string, string> petOwnerDict = pets
    .ToDictionary(item => item.name, item => item.owner);
```

Otherwise, what you already have in `linqPetOwner` (a collection of anonymous types) should be sufficient unless you're trying to pass this outside the context. Just add a `.ToList()` on the end:

```
var petOwners = pets.Select(pet => new {pet.name, pet.owner}).ToList();
```

And of course, if you're just trying to output the names and owners to the console, you don't need to create any new collection for that, you just output the properties you care about:

```
foreach (var pet in pets)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{pet.name} is owned by {pet.owner}");
}
```

Comment: No point in introducing ToDictionary because they are going to iterate through the elements to do the console.writeline anyways.

Comment: @terrencep Yeah, it's not clear to me if they just want to write two properties to the console, or if they want to create a collection of "smaller objects". I've updated answer with how to write the two properties to the console without creating any new collections.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, much appreciated! The .ToDictionary() explanation is good too.